# TypeError: users.map is not a function in Mern

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to fetch data from backend, I want to load all data which are in database, when I load function then getting an error like "User.map is not a function", please let me know where am wrong.

> User.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUsers } from "./apis";

const UserData = () => {
  const [users, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    AllUsers();
  }, []);

  const AllUsers = async () => {
    const response = await getUsers();
    console.log(response.data);
    setUser(response.data ? response.data : []);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {/* <th scope="col">No</th> */}
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Details</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                <td>{user.title}</td>
                <td>{user.description}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

> Api.js

I have added api.js file please check it , and let me know where am wrong

```
export default UserData;

import Axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:3000/";

export const getUsers = async (id) => {
  id = id || "";
  return await Axios.get(`${url}/${id}`);
};

export const deleteUser = async (id) => {
  return await Axios.delete(`${url}/${id}`);
};
```

Comment: Your response.data is not an array. This has caused the error. Make sure that response.data inside AllUsers is an array.

Comment: @RajeshPaudel AllUser is an array ... can you tell me how to fix error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for check the data is available or not. Because while API's is calling data not set in your `state`. It's might be a `undefined`.

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
```

In your case do with this way.

```
          {users?.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                <td>{user.title}</td>
                <td>{user.description}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
```

```
import Axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:3000/";

export const getUsers = async (id) => {
  id = id || "";
  return await Axios.get(`${url}/${id}`);
};

export const deleteUser = async (id) => {
  return await Axios.delete(`${url}/${id}`);
};
```

Comment: i did your method but its not working for me , still getting an same error

Comment: Could you please how your `getUsers` method